# How to run the tup build system on Windows 8 64bit?

Tags: windows, build, tup

I successfully use the [tup build system](http://gittup.org/tup/index.html) on a Debian based system.
According to the website, it should also run under Windows. I downloaded the latest version from their website for Windows, unzipped it and added the directory to the PATH env variable.

Unfortunately, I always get the following error: tup error: failed to create child process: No such file or directory

Did anyone manage to run tup under Win 8 64bit? How?

Comment: What tool are you trying to run in tup? What's the exact command? Have you tried the most simple command like "|> echo hello > file.txt |> file.txt"?

Answer (score 1):

Tup has added support for 64-bit Windows only recently (see the original commit [here](https://github.com/gittup/tup/commit/8131823aeb11370d663bac3ee5e0feeb4f23fdd2)).

Since tup uses DLL injection to intercept the file-system and process-creation operations, it needed to have both 32-bit and 64-bit DLLs and properly working injection mechanism for both platforms.